# How to add a button to ACF tiny MCE editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, advanced-custom-fields

How can i add a button to ACF WYSIWYG editor ( for example 'text color' button ).
i tried this code but it doesn't work :(

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'dw_add_buttons_to_acf_wysiwyg_editor'  );
function dw_add_buttons_to_acf_wysiwyg_editor( $toolbars ){
    $toolbars['Full'][2][] = 'forecolor';

    return $toolbars;
}
```