# How do you add Text Color Button to Advanced Custom Fields TinyMCE Basic toolbar?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, advanced-custom-fields

By default ACF has two choices for the WYSIWYG custom field regarding toolbars, Full and Basic.  These are both great but I just need one more button( maybe more in another project) in the Basic toolbar.

I am trying to add the text-color picker to the Basic toolbar.

Based on this documentation here, [ACF Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/customize-the-wysiwyg-toolbars/), I came up with this:

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'my_toolbars'  );
function my_toolbars( $toolbars ) {
    array_unshift( $toolbars['Basic' ] , 'forecolor' );
    return $toolbars;
}
```

I also looked at this past question,["How to add a button to ACF tiny MCE editor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462326/how-to-add-a-button-to-acf-tiny-mce-editor), but didn't find the links provided very clear in producing a result(maybe partially because comments were in French).

I am guessing it has something to do with what was said in that questions comments about missing the plugin for that button.  But I am unsure, any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some help from the [Advanced Custom Fields Support Forum](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-do-you-add-text-color-button-to-tinymce-basic-toolbar/#post-22911), I found out that my code was prepending to the outer array and I needed to target the nested array to add the button.

This is the code that works to add the Font Color button to the Basic Toolbar:

```
add_filter( 'acf/fields/wysiwyg/toolbars' , 'my_toolbars'  );
function my_toolbars( $toolbars ) {
    array_unshift( $toolbars['Basic' ][1], 'forecolor' );
    return $toolbars;
}
```

Comment: Where do you write this code? In the Plugin Source?